# tools to measure asp .net web application performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc

HI,

Can anyone suggest good tools to analyze asp .net application performance and find the bottle necks?

Thanks SA

Comment: Is nants profiler helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have had great luck with Redgate's ANTS Profiler: http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm

It allowed us to find our slowest methods and start working on improving each one with measurable results. They even have a free trial that is not limited (as far as we could tell).

I suggest trying that out.

Answer (score 1):

First, start using basic tools like yslow (a firefox addon for any web application).
Now there are various aspects to performance testing depending on what you want to test you have to chose appropriate tools.

You can find some information [here](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~electionreddy/projects/sem2/seminar/perfTest.pdf) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have IIS logs enabled, you can take a look at the slowest pages by using the [LogParser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx).

Also keep an eye on performance counters like Current Requests, [Queued Requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), etc.  If you are having lots of queue requests, it may be time to start using async as your ASP.NET threads are just idle waiting for other resources.

You may also want to check out [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) to obtain stack information in a production environment for long/slow requests.